# What show_hide not trigger the click function?

Tags: jquery, class

I have a button which will run the following query. I can see the glyphicon-minus icon. I don't see anything happen if I click on it.

```
var $newpage = $("<div class='page edit' id='divPage_" + pageID + "' style='display: block;'><a href='#' class='show_hide'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></a> <span class='page title edit' id='" + pageID + "'>" + pageName + "</span><div class='section new' style='display: block;'><span class='section title new' id='-1'>New Section</span></div></div>");
$newpage.insertBefore($(selection));

$('.show_hide').click(function (e) { alert('a'); }
```

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', '.show_hide', function(e) { ...`, let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

Since this is content you're adding after the page loads you want to use event delegation. Something like the following should work:

```
$(selection).parent().on('click', '.show_hide', function(e) {
    alert('a');
});
```

Or, the new element isn't too deep in the DOM tree:

```
$(document).on('click', '.show_hide', function(e) {
    alert('a');
});
```

[**event delegation**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the jquery part

```
$('document').on('click', '.show_hide', function (e) {   
    e.preventDefault();alert('a'); 
});
```